# Gradle: 'dependsOn' to task in other subproject

Tags: gradle, dependencies, war

I have a hierarchical gradle 3.1 project, which looks like this:

```
root
    - build.gradle
    - settings.gradle
    - server (Java + WAR plugin)
        - build.gradle
    - client (Node plugin)
        - build.gradle
```

The `settings.gradle` therefore looks like this:

```
include ':server', ':client'
```

What I would like to do now is to bundle the output of the `:client:build` task  in the `*.war` file produced by the `:server:war` task. To do so, I need a dependency from `:server:war` to `:client:build` in order to ensure that the output files of `:client:build` are always present when I need to copy them in the `:server:war` task.

The question is: **how does this work?**

**What I want to achieve here:** whenever `:server:war` is executed, `:client:build` gets executed *first*.

#### Things I tried so far (none of them worked):

```
// in server/build.gradle
task war {
    dependsOn ':client:build'
}
```

I also tried:

```
// in server/build.gradle
war.dependsOn = ':client:build'
```

... and also:

```
// in server/build.gradle
task war(dependsOn: ':client:build') {

}
```

None of the attempts above works. Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Please try just:

```
war.dependsOn ':client:build'
```

and:

```
task war {
    dependsOn ':client:build'
}
```

defines a new task called `war`

and:

```
war.dependsOn = ':client:build'
```

theoretically calls [this](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/Task.html#setDependsOn(java.lang.Iterable)) method but the argument has wrong type

and:

```
task war(dependsOn: ':client:build') {
}
```

here you define a new task as well.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I just tried your first proposal, and even though I could have sworn that I tried this before already - it works! Maybe it's because I ran a `gradlew clean` in between, I'm not sure. Thanks!

Comment: There is a special place in heaven for the writers of this question and answer!  Several hours of pain and looking through gradle doc and the answer is here.  Thanks!